# Slur With Mixed Syllabics

Tags: lilypond

In my score, I have two verses where in verse 1, the slur should have one syllable per note in the slur, but in verse 2, the one word should apply to both notes.

You can see that in verse one the `four` gets lost.  It is supposed to line up with the last part of the slur.

```
\version "2.19.80"

\header {
    title = "Slur with mixed Syllabics"
}

signature = {
    \time 4/4
    \key c \major
}

Verses = \relative c'{
    %\set Score.melismaBusyProperties = #'()
    %\autoBeamOff
    c4^\markup{ \bold Mixed Syllabics }  c'4 \stemDown a8( c4.) \stemNeutral
    \bar "||"
}

LyricsOne =\lyricmode {
    \set stanza = #"1."
    one two three four    %the "four" gets lost
}

LyricsTwo = \lyricmode {
    \set stanza = # "2."
    one two three_  %should last for both notes in the slur
}

Joined = <<
    \new Voice = "VerseChorus" {  \Verses }
    \new Lyrics { \lyricsto "VerseChorus" { \LyricsOne } }
    \new Lyrics { \lyricsto "VerseChorus" { \LyricsTwo } }
>>

\score {
        <<
        \new Staff{   
                \autoBeamOff
                \signature
                \tempo 4=110
                \Joined    
             }
        >>
    \layout {
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here for various ways the developers suggest solving this problem: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/stanzas#stanzas-with-different-rhythms

The way that I usually choose is this:

> One possibility is that the text has a melisma in one stanza, but multiple syllables in another. One solution is to make the faster voice ignore the melisma. This is done by setting ignoreMelismata in the Lyrics context.

For instance, in your music (simplified for the sake of this example):

```
\version "2.18.2"
Verses = \relative c'{
 c4 c'4 a8( c4.)
}
LyricsOne =\lyricmode {
 one two \set Lyrics.ignoreMelismata = ##t three four \set Lyrics.ignoreMelismata = ##f
}
LyricsTwo = \lyricmode {
 one two three_
}
\score {
 \new Staff <<
  \new Voice = "VerseChorus" \Verses
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "VerseChorus" \LyricsOne
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "VerseChorus" \LyricsTwo
 >>
}
```

[image: Lyrics with different syllable counts going to same melody in LilyPond]

Answer (score 2):

If you have different syllable distributions for the same melody, you can't print them below each other and expect the music to fit everything. Even if you wrote a dashed slur trying to express "This slur applies to some but not all stanzas", it's still unclear to which stanzas it applies.

However, if you really want a mixed score like this, the most simplt fix is to keep the slur and just pretend that "three four" is one syllable, by writing

`one two "three four"`

instead of

`one two three four`

(These words fit really badly under your example notes, but that has nothing to do with the different stanzas.)